# Is it possible to listen to an event in a component and change the native element?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

My component uses a class in pure JS that creates the DOM elements and returns them to the template by reference:

```
@ViewChild ("layersContainer", {static: true}) layersContainer: ElementRef;
<div class = "Layers" #layersContainer> </div>
```

I pass the `#layersContainer` reference to the container to this class:

`new DomBuilderJs (this.layersContainer);`

Is it possible to somehow listen in a component for changes in the DOM is not built by the component?

More precisely, listen to the hover for a specific element and modify it already on the component side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating selector directive and adding event listener using the hostlistener. Some like shown below

```
    import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[layersContainer]'})
export class LayerContainerSelectorDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef)

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.elementRef.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```